# the meaning of "all these others " in the context and the sentence meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am confused of the meaning of **"all these others "** in the context.

> So continuing with ice ages, we've looked at the Pleistocene Ice Age up through the so-called Little Ice Age in Europe, but today I'd like to talk about a controversial hypothesis that Earth went through tremendous ice ages before **all these others** between approximately 600 and 700 million years ago during a geologic period that's known as the Cryogenian.

Comment: [confused **by** the meaning of etc.]

Answer (score 1):

> all these **other ice ages**

*Others* means *the ones that aren't this one* or *the different ones than this one*.

This sentence is talking about certain *ice ages* (periods of time when the Earth was covered in ice). However, some people have a *hypothesis* (a guess that describes why something happens) that before those ice ages, the Earth had bigger ice ages. This time was called the *Cryogenian period* that happened 600 - 700 million years ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  you are really nice ~~
Can I understand this sentence like : 
Today, I'd like to focus on if the earth went through a bigger ice ages in a special period called "Cryogenian" before the Pleistocene Ice Age  in the period called " Little Ice Age"
And some people think it is, some people don't thinks so.

Comment: @Eva The sentence is talking about a period called the _Little Ice Age_ that took place before the Pleistocene Ice Age. Some people think it is true, and some people don't.

Comment: @Eva Bear in mind that this is spontaneous speech and is not very well said. But this answer is correct.